# Combining uboot and Linux Kernel Image and deploying to Target Device without File System

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, buildroot

I have a compiled linux kernel in the form of uImage for the target device

I also have uboot image for the target device. However, I need an img file that takes the uboot and kernel image and combines them along with the file system to create an image for the device.

**Question**: Can I manually consolidate uboot and kernel by simply partition the SD card and copy paste kernel image and uboot image, without file system and deploy into the target device? Why do I need a buildroot to do that for me?

Comment: The answer depends on the target device.  For ARM architecture each SoC could have its own boot procedure depending on the boot medium; MIPS could be similar(?).  Some SoCs access boot files from SD card using raw LBA access.  Others expect a VFAT filesystem.  U-Boot can be built to fetch a kernel image from raw device or various filesystems, e.g. ext4.  I prefer to use a filesystem when possible, as that allows backups and alternate versions.

Comment: @sawdust so technically we dont necessarily need filesystem?  I acknowledge that `U-Boot can be built to fetch a kernel image from raw device or various filesystems` perhaps thats exactly my understanding of U-Boot is that it fetches the kernel. But what I am keen to know that i can simply partition the SD card (assuming target device boots from SD card) so in one partition I manually copy/paste Uboot image for target device and in another partition I manually copy paste kernel, (will that work in terms of having a functioning device?)

Comment: *"so technically we dont necessarily need filesystem?"* -- That all depends on how the specific SoC ROM code loads the SPL or U-Boot.  Once U-Boot is executing, then it is in control from where & how the kernel image is fetched.  In theory you could setup U-Boot to do whatever you choose.  But if the SoC does require a VFAT filesystem, there is no sense in going back to raw access for the kernel.

Comment: @sawdust makes soo much sense! reading your comments made me realize that I was wrongly thinking of filesystem as those folders that are there by default such as `/sys /opt /bin /media` etc that linux provides so userland program communicates with kernel! I dont know what I thought of these! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [genimage](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage) tool does exactly what you need. It is available in Buildroot in the "Host utilities" menu.

Many of the board configurations in the `configs` directory use genimage to create an SD card image, so they can server as inspiration.